# How to fix Unknown or uninitialised column: error in R tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I ran into a very persistent, troublesome "Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gdd_runsum'" error today.  I've looked for errors or problems with my code that might be causing it, but I can't find any.  I actually ran this same code a couple days ago with no problems.  Is there something in my code that would cause this error, telling me that a column name that is nowhere to be found in my code is uninitialized?

```
    corn <- read.csv('I:\\HATCH_Project\\Corn.csv')
    corn <- corn[corn$Single == 'Yes',]
    corn$County[which(corn$County == 'Mcpherson')] <- 'McPherson'
    corn$County[which(corn$County == 'Mccook')] <- 'McCook'
    corn_df_values <- data.frame(corn$Year,corn$County,corn$Value); colnames(corn_df_values) <- c('Year','County','Yield')
    
    corn_final <- corn_df_values %>% pivot_wider(names_from = County, values_from = Yield)
    corn_final <- corn_final[order(corn_final$Year),]
    corn_final_wide <- corn_final %>% tibble %>% select("Year", sort(colnames(.)))
    corn_final_long <- corn_final_wide %>% pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = 'County', values_to = 'Yield')
    corn_final_long <- corn_final_long[-which(is.na(corn_final_long$Yield)),]
    corn_by_county <- corn_final_long %>% group_by(County) %>% mutate(n = n())
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% group_by(County,n) %>% nest()

    gdd_runsum_df <- tibble(Date = seq(as.Date('2020-04-01'),as.Date('2020-11-01'),by='day'))
    gdd_runsum_df$month <- month(gdd_runsum_df$Date); gdd_runsum_df$day <- day(gdd_runsum_df$Date)
    gdd_runsum_df$runsum1 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum5 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum10 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum15 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum20 <- NA; 
    gdd_runsum_df$runsum25 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum30 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum35 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum40 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum45 <- NA;
    gdd_runsum_df$runsum50 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum60 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum70 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum75 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum80 <- NA; gdd_runsum_df$runsum90 <- NA;

    for (cty in 1:66){
      yield_model <- lm(corn_by_county$data[[cty]]$Yield ~ corn_by_county$data[[cty]]$Year)
      corn_by_county$data[[cty]]$Det_Yield <- as.numeric(resid(yield_model))}
    
    #GDD
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gdd_min_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df))) 
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gdd_mean_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df)))
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gdd_median_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df))) 
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gdd_max_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df))) 
    #GDDmod
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gddmod_min_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df))) 
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gddmod_mean_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df)))
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gddmod_median_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df))) 
    corn_by_county <- corn_by_county %>% mutate(gddmod_max_runsum = list(as_tibble(gdd_runsum_df)))
```

Not only does that error show up, but when I try to run this code, it fails, giving a NULL result.  It seems to have something to do with the error above, since they both happened at the same time.  The code above is only a small sample - I am trying to make a very large tibble with over 200 variables.  Maybe that's the problem, I don't know.  Any help would be great.

```
junk <- cat(capture.output(dput(colnames(corn_by_county)[4:11])))


corn <- structure(list(Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), State = c("SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA", 
"SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH DAKOTA"), Ag_District = c("CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", 
"CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", 
"NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTHEAST", 
"NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHWEST", "NORTHWEST", "SOUTH CENTRAL", 
"SOUTH CENTRAL", "SOUTH CENTRAL", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", 
"SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", 
"CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", 
"CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", 
"NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", 
"NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTH CENTRAL", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", 
"NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHEAST", "NORTHWEST", 
"NORTHWEST", "NORTHWEST", "SOUTH CENTRAL", "SOUTH CENTRAL", "SOUTH CENTRAL", 
"SOUTH CENTRAL", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", 
"SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHEAST", "SOUTHWEST", 
"SOUTHWEST", "SOUTHWEST", "WEST CENTRAL", "WEST CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", 
"CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", "CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL", 
"EAST CENTRAL", "EAST CENTRAL"), Ag_District_Code = c(50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 10L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 70L, 70L, 
70L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L), County = c("Aurora", "Brule", 
"Buffalo", "Hand", "Jerauld", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Lake", 
"Mccook", "Minnehaha", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Brown", 
"Edmunds", "Mcpherson", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Spink", 
"Deuel", "Grant", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Other (Combined) Counties", 
"Ziebach", "Lyman", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Tripp", "Bon Homme", 
"Charles Mix", "Douglas", "Lincoln", "Other (Combined) Counties", 
"Turner", "Union", "Yankton", "Aurora", "Beadle", "Brule", "Hand", 
"Hughes", "Hyde", "Jerauld", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Brookings", 
"Kingsbury", "Lake", "Mccook", "Miner", "Minnehaha", "Moody", 
"Other (Combined) Counties", "Sanborn", "Brown", "Campbell", 
"Edmunds", "Faulk", "Mcpherson", "Potter", "Spink", "Walworth", 
"Clark", "Deuel", "Grant", "Hamlin", "Marshall", "Other (Combined) Counties", 
"Roberts", "Corson", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Ziebach", 
"Gregory", "Lyman", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Tripp", "Charles Mix", 
"Clay", "Hutchinson", "Lincoln", "Other (Combined) Counties", 
"Turner", "Union", "Yankton", "Bennett", "Custer", "Other (Combined) Counties", 
"Meade", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Aurora", "Beadle", "Brule", 
"Hand", "Hughes", "Other (Combined) Counties", "Sully", "Brookings", 
"Davison", "Hanson", "Kingsbury", "Lake", "Mccook", "Miner", 
"Minnehaha", "Moody", "Sanborn"), Commodity = c("CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "CORN"), Value = c(133.9, 147.6, 133.5, 142.2, 142.6, 
128.8, 145.5, 129.3, 161.1, 138.7, 164.2, 133.4, 147.1, 138.9, 
152.9, 144, 146.3, 157.8, 116.4, 97.5, 131, 117.6, 119.1, 160.6, 
148.7, 149, 163.8, 161.9, 161.1, 178.7, 170, 164.3, 159.7, 168.9, 
138.3, 106, 125.7, 147.5, 101.3, 198.9, 184.5, 192.7, 177.9, 
178.7, 191.5, 194.1, 171.6, 167.2, 155.4, 129.6, 117.3, 103.2, 
108.7, 109, 160, 146.5, 177.5, 190.6, 185.1, 191.8, 184.6, 178, 
191.8, 91.9, 78.1, 78.8, 157.4, 120.7, 96.3, 124.7, 177.7, 179.6, 
166.8, 161.9, 165.1, 176.3, 186.2, 175.6, 128.7, 100, 98.2, 87.8, 
59, 122.1, 137.7, 106.5, 117, 100.7, 101.5, 100.3, 188.2, 127.2, 
152.9, 167.7, 183.8, 171.1, 163.4, 185.9, 187.7, 154.3), Single = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share only the relevant lines of the code that give you an error instead of sharing the entire script?

Comment: I shared the script so you can run it and get the error yourself.  More than one line gives the error.

Comment: When I run the script I get error in `for` loop `Error in corn_by_county$data[[cty]] : subscript out of bounds`. Do you have the same error? I don't get `"Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gdd_runsum'" `

Comment: Instead of 1:66, it should be 1:50, since this is a small data sample.  When I open a new R Script and paste the code in the new script, it works fine.  Maybe I just need to write a new .R script.  Ugh.  Frustrating.  Thank you for trying!